# Azure Devops Build: trying to get the last changes when PR is merged

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

## Requirement

Whenever a feature needs to be deployed to en environment a PR is created. To complete this PR some builds need to be validated first. Only when this is done we can complete the PR.

After the PR is completed and merged. A Build is triggered on the target (environment) branch. This will deploy the changes.

## Issue

After to completion and merge of the PR  build is triggered that will take the last changes  through git diff and deploy it. I take the last changes through this command

```
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD^ HEAD
```

Whenever this is executed I receive the following error.

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
##[error]Bash exited with code '128'.
```

But after that I trigger the build manually and then the git diff works and the deploy happens smoothly.

## Question

Why does it give an error when it is automatically triggered through a commit on the target (environment) branch, and why does it work when I trigger it manually?

These are the commands I already tried, without success
$ git log -1 --name-only --oneline
OR
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d HEAD^ HEAD
OR
$ git diff --name-only --diff-filter= @~..@

Comment: It's almost certainly a clone-depth issue, with the CI system making a shallow clone so that there is no `HEAD^` commit. What's not clear (but will be CI-system-dependent) is why it works on a manual trigger. Note that you might want to use `-n 2` as a minimum for `git log` when trying to debug this, to see if there are in fact two commits.

Comment: Update: When doing git log -1 it gives me the initial commit. So I get the list of files that were added in the initial commit.

Comment: Hi RomeoRomeo; can I ask why you need to do a git diff? Is there some reason you can't just check out the latest code (in the environment branch) and deploy that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New pipelines created after the September 2022 Azure DevOps sprint 209 update have Shallow fetch enabled by default and configured with a depth of 1. If your repository is large, this option might make your build pipeline more efficient.

You can configure the Shallow fetch setting from the properties of the Get sources task in your pipeline. Like increase the depth to 5. Refer to [Shallow fetch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic#shallow-fetch) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Thank you @suki!! Solved it. "There is a small window between when a branch is resolved to a commit ID and when the agent performs the checkout. If the branch updates rapidly and you set a very small value for shallow fetch, the commit may not exist when the agent attempts to check it out. If that happens, increase the shallow fetch depth setting."